# Join multiple tables with main table

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a main SQL-Table. This table is conneted to some more tables via  "linking"-tables, because there could be multiple entries in both directions.

```
Main: id_main, title, content

Table2: id_table2, content
LinkTable2: id_main, id_table2

Table3: id_table3, content
LinkTable3: id_main, id_table3
```

Now I want to get the complete data. This is my attempt to connect just one table with the main table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Main 
INNER JOIN LinkTable2 ON LinkTable2.id_main = Main.id_main 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON LinkTable2.id_table2 = Table2.id_table2
```

How do I connect multiple tables (with multiple results)?

Comment: I need that 'linkin' tables because of the multiple relations between the data.

Comment: Can you add sample data an the expected result? It is much better as most explanation.

Comment: @nobodynoone He clearly explains in the first sentence why there are linking tables. It's fairly clear that he wants to extend the query to join Table3 via LinkTable3. I'm pretty bored of people rubbishing questions that they haven't even tried to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep going!

```
SELECT *
  FROM Main m 
  JOIN LinkTable2 lt2 
    ON lt2.id_main = m.id_main 
  JOIN Table2 t2 
    ON t2.id_table2 = lt2.id_table2
  JOIN LinkTable3 lt3
    ON lt3.id_main = m.id_main 
  JOIN Table2 t3 
    ON t3.id_table3 = lt3.id_table3
```

Comment: Oh damn. Just that simple.